# how to create a custom application in twitter?

Tags: objective-c

I’m trying to register a custom application in twitter can any one give some suggestions how to register a custom application in twitter? As I am new to twitter I didn’t found any controls to create to register for creating a custom application. Anyone's help will be much appreciated.

Thank you,
Monish.

Comment: Could you make the question a bit more clear? I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Do you mean you want to write an application that posts tweets?

Comment: yes I want to write an application that posts tweets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [MGTwitterEngine](http://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine) to get you started and then ask more specific questions.